# Javascript: Load Xml file from Isolated Storage in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I am building Html5 application for Windows Phone 8. How can I load Xml file from Isolated Storage by JavaScript? I did not find any example.

Comment: Are you using any framework like PhoneGap? You cannot do that directly, there has to be some sort of proxy between the isostore and your js code.

Comment: Are you developing a native application with web browser control ?